# Protect Firebase Http Cloud Functions Using JWT Tokens or any other mechanism without using firebase user authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

**Edited**

I am building a spa app to make some administrative tasks on the app/firebase easier. I don't have a separate backend for this app so I use firebase cloud functions directly from the spa client. I am also **not using** Admin Sdk , just Http triggers. I am using `functions.https.onCall` on  functions invoked by regular app users. Since i didn't want to mix up regular users with the admin login , I implemented a separate login for the spa app. Since the admin is already logged in , I am looking for some kind of JWT key / API key based authentication to  secure  firebase functions implemented for these tasks.

One possible solution , as Frank van Puffelen mentioned in his answer , is to add firebase auth , store the UIDs of the admin users and check if the request came from them using `getIdToken()` in the cloud function. Is this the best practice or is there an alternate to approach this.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is too broad at the moment, because the short answer is just "Yes, it's possible" as any authentication method you can come up with can be used. You could use any express-based method, a simple API secret key or just use Firebase Authentication. You'll need to add in some additional requirements to narrow down the scope. Also remember that SO is not a platform for general advice on how to write/structure your app, it's a question-answer platform around specific code-related problems.

Comment: @samthecodingman  Appreciate the response, edited the question to be more specific. I am exactly looking to implement some API secret key but don't know how to implement it. Also what would be a better platform for these kind of questions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common approaches here are to:

- Either keep a list of the UIDs of the admin users in a place that your Cloud Function can access, for example in the code itself or (more likely) in a cloud-hosted database.
- Or [add a custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk) to the ID token of admin users.

In either case, your Cloud Functions code can then ensure the user is authorized to call the end point.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I edited my question to be more specific. First point is a  possible solution but that means i have to add firebase auth to my admin app. I'm looking to avoid it if possible . As for the second point, I'm not using admin sdk.